# Растянуть элемент на всю ширину

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как растянуть элемент на всю ширину если у родителя уже задано ограничение в ширине в 1000px? Причем, без абсолютного позиционирования или сделать так, чтобы в определенном моменте это позиционирование убрать, что бы он не был поверх нижних элементов, футера например.

Comment: тут вариантов кроме абсолютного позиционирования и width: 100% для внутреннего дива (+z-index по необходимости), особо нету. Возможно, стоит оптимизировать саму структуру документа. Попробуйте привести пример разметки тут.

Answer (score 3):

Для современных браузеров можно использовать такой вариант:

для нужного элемента прописать стили:

```
width: 100vw;
margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
```

Answer (score 1):

Положите оба блока в один общий блок с шириной равной ширине экрана и задайте этому общему блока overflow-x: hidden. Затем блоку который хотите растянуть на ширину экрана задайте св-ва вроде таких

```
position: absolute;
left: -3000px;
right: -3000px;
```

Такой блок не будет перекрывать нижеидущие по коду блоки. Если этот блок имеет заданную высоту и должен идти фоном, то следующие блоки можно, например, "поднять" отрицательным margin-top

Answer (score 0):

Я не особо понял вопрос, но `width: 100%;` не? и `z-index` не?

Answer (score 0):

width: 100%; дает размеры родителя

Answer (score -1):

Воспользуйтесь свойством `position: relative;` относительно блока наследника и примените к нему `width: 100%;`. Это должно растянуть упомянутый блок на всю ширину родителя

Comment: Вы растягиваете блок на ширину родителя. А в вопросе просят растянуть шире ширины родителя.